# how to write C shared lib using in C++ code

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I have some C++ source code, something like below:

```
class IChecker{
public:
    int Init(void);
};
...
void *hdll = dlopen("libtest.so", RTLD_NOW);
...
IChecker *pCheck = dlsym(hDll,"CreateChecker");//get addr of "CreateChecker" in lib 
...
(*pCheck)()->Init();
```

How should I write `libtest.so` using C, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You want to write a shared lib that creates a pointer to an object that's binary compatible with the IChecker class (that's going to be hackish and fragile), or is the code above just to prove you have some idea how `dlopen` and `dlsym` work and you just want some normal C data and functions exposed?

Comment: do you want usage of extern C{ } to export the function/variables from c lib.

Comment: @TonyD the **former** is what i want,is the object returned from shared lib **must** compatible with the IChecker absolutely? can u show me a example?

Comment: @jiych.guru ICheck or IChecker ?

Comment: @bikram990 sorry,it's a typo

Comment: @jiych.guru: well, the details are compiler/system dependent.  Further, I don't believe IChecker as illustrated is useful, and assume you actually want some virtual functions in there.  Once that enters the picture, you'd be crazy to write the shared lib in C and not C++.

Comment: @TonyD actually,there're only some virtual functions in IChecker,so my idea is impossible nearly?:)

Comment: Yes, nearly. Specifically, `CreateChecker` would need to create a derived object that's properly aligned and binary compatible with a C++-created object, including a pointer to the virtual dispatch table / RTTI information. To do that, it would be easiest to insist that the C++ code first called the C code with pointers to reference objects: then you could `memcpy` them to get the implementation-needed pointers and overwrite the data members you're interested in if you know (hardcode or have C++ tell) their offsets. But, it's ugly and fragile. Why wouldn't you want to write the .so in C++?

Comment: @TonyD thank u for your thorough expressions.just cause i'm not familiar with C++,seem not good reason:)

Comment: @jiych.guru: well, to get you started you can code C++ pretty much like C... just using the virtual functions that your C++ client code's obviously expecting and whatever features you're comfortable with. C++ is pretty much a super-set of C so you can ease into: I'd just recommend learning about vector, map and string quickly - only take 15 minutes and helps with so many programs. The rest can come if/when you feel like it or have reason to delve deeper.  There are C++ snobs who pick on such code, but ignore them - what works works and a comfortable step into C++ is better than none.